# Sane way to go from ArrayList<Long> through an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, long-integer

I'm currently writing an app that pulls an array of longs from a server via json, and then passes that list from one activity into another.  The basic skeleton looks like this:

```
public void onResponse(Map result)
{
    ArrayList handles= (ArrayList)result.get("fileHandles");

    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("handles", handles);
}
```

So the first problem becomes evident, the only methods for putExtra are `putIntegerArrayListExtra`, `putStringArrayListExtra`, `putCharSequenceArrayListExtra`, and `putParcelableArrayListExtra`.  Thinking Long would probably be parcelable, I was wrong it doesn't work (even if I use `ArrayList<Long>`).  Next I thought I'd just pass a long [], however I see no straight-forward conversion to go from `ArrayList<Long>` to long [] that `intent.putExtra` will accept.  This was the solution I finally ended up with:

```
ArrayList handles= (ArrayList)result.get("fileHandles");
long [] handleArray = new long[handles.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < handles.size(); i++)
{
    handleArray[i] = Long.parseLong(handles.get(i).toString());
}
```

Obviously this seemed a little bit ridiculous to me, but every other conversion I tried seemed to complain for one reason or another.  I've thought about re-thinking my serialization to have the problem taken care of before I get to this point, but I find it odd that passing `ArrayList<Long>` from activity to activity could be so difficult.  Is there a more obvious solution I'm missing?

Comment: FWIW: `Long.parseLong(handles.get(i).toString());` can be written as `(long)(Long)handles.get(i)` (the `(long)` is actually optional in context) when the source is an `ArrayList<Long>`. It uses a dowcast and then an explicit (or implicit) un-autobox instead of Long->String->long.

Comment: @user2864740 The problem is `handles.get(i)` is giving me back an Integer if it's under 2 billion or so, which results in an invalid cast if I use that code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use it as a `Serializable` extra. `ArrayList` is `Serializable` and `Long` extends `Number` which also implements `Serializable`:

```
// Put as Serializable
i.putExtra("handles", handles);

// Unfortunately you'll get an unsafe cast warning here, but it's safe to use
ArrayList<Long> handles = (ArrayList<Long>) i.getSerializableExtra("handles");
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `putSerializable` as an option on `Intent`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was looking at `Bundle`, not `Intent`. See the edit. :)

Comment: Got it, much simpler, thanks very much.  Feels good to delete all that terrible code I just wrote.

Comment: It is not so memory efficient. Please see: http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Answer (score 3):

Two options: Use `Parcelable` or `Serializable`

in:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("handles", new FileHandles(handles));
```

out:

```
FileHandles handles = intent.getParcelableExtra("handles");
```

object:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileHandles implements Parcelable {

    private final List<Long> fileHandles;

    public FileHandles(List<Long> fileHandles) {
        this.fileHandles = fileHandles;
    }

    public FileHandles(Parcel in) {
        int size = in.readInt();
        long[] parcelFileHandles = new long[size];
        in.readLongArray(parcelFileHandles);
        this.fileHandles = toObjects(size, parcelFileHandles);
    }

    private List<Long> toObjects(int size, long[] parcelFileHandles) {
        List<Long> primitiveConv = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            primitiveConv.add(parcelFileHandles[i]);
        }
        return primitiveConv;
    }

    public List<Long> asList() { // Prefer you didn't use this method & added domain login here, but stackoverflow can only teach so much..
        return fileHandles;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(fileHandles.size());
        dest.writeLongArray(toPrimitives(fileHandles));
    }

    private static long[] toPrimitives(List<Long> list) {
        return toPrimitives(list.toArray(new Long[list.size()]));
    }

    public static long[] toPrimitives(Long... objects) {
        long[] primitives = new long[objects.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
            primitives[i] = objects[i];

        return primitives;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        @Override
        public FileHandles createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new FileHandles(in);
        }

        @Override
        public FileHandles[] newArray(int size) {
            return new FileHandles[size];
        }
    };
}
```

---

Serializable (forced to use `ArrayList` which implements `Serializable` (`List` does not)

in:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("handles", new ArrayList<Long>());
```

out:

```
    ArrayList handles = (ArrayList) intent.getSerializableExtra("handles");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I looked into the parcelable option but it seemed worse than the ugly conversion.  The `Serializable` options seems to be the easiest solution to the problem.

Comment: `Serializable` with a forced use of `ArrayList` is the easier option. `Parcelable` is Androids version of `Serializable` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html it is optimised for mobile and large data sets. I would always recommend `Serializable` but if you have 1000's of items in your list and pass it around a lot, I would recommend you research `Parcelable` to consider as a performance gain

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in mind.  I think it'll be OK in my use case, it's no more than 5-10 long values.